# Starting Jenkins pipeline with Gerrit trigger - regular expression

Tags: regex, jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit

I need to trigger a Jenkins build pipeline for N projects. These are stored in a Gerrit and their names have a pattern like this:

```
MODEL_A, MODEL_B, MODEL_C, etc.
```

So, in my opinion the best would be to use a regular expression for the comparison:

```
pipeline
    ...
    triggers {
        gerrit(
                gerritProjects: [[
                compareType: 'REG_EXP',
                pattern : '**/MODEL_[A|B|C]**',
                branches : [[
                    compareType: 'REG_EXP',
                    pattern : '**'
                ]]
            ]],
            triggerOnEvents: [[
                $class : 'PluginPatchsetCreatedEvent',
                excludeDrafts : false,
                excludeTrivialRebase: false,
                excludeNoCodeChange : false
            ]]
        )
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that, no matter where I do the commit, no project is built. The patter is not a PCRE compliant patternand on the offigial Jenkis Gerrit trigger page is no example for such case.

Any hint with this regex?

Comment: What is the actual pattern you are using in your script?  Are those `**` actually part of the pattern, or did you just add them for emphasis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from:

```
pattern : '**/MODEL_[A|B|C]**'
```

To:

```
pattern : '.*\/MODEL_[A-C].*'
```